# Getting Around Bad Design Practices: Java Multiple Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, javafx

I am working with the JavaFX `Shape` subclasses, and I have run into what I believe is a rather strange issue. My goal is to extend several of these shape subclasses (i.e. `Rectangle`, `Circle`) in order to add my own attributes to these objects. For example, the extension of the `Rectangle` subclass would look like this:

```
public class MyRectangle extends javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle 
    implements SpecialInterface {

    private SpecialAttributes specialAttributes;

    // ...
    // Constructors, getters and setters here
    // ...
}
```

Where the `SpecialInterface` can be used to specify the methods related to the new attributes that will be added to `MyRectangle` and `MyCircle`, in this case:

```
public interface SpecialInterface {

    public SpecialAttributes getSpecialAttributes();
    public void setSpecialAttributes();

}
```

However, when I try to create service classes that reference these subclasses of `Rectangle` and `Circle`, it seems as though I cannot do so generically. Essentially, the problem arises when I need to utilize attributes and methods from both the `Shape` subclasses and the `SpecialInterface` interface:

```
public class ManipulationService{

    public ManipulationService(<Undefined> myExtendedShape) {
        // object from JavaFX Node, inherited by JavaFX Shapes (Circle, Rectangle, etc)
        myExtendedShape.onRotate(new EventHandler<>(){
            // ...
        });

        // a method from MyRectangle or MyCircle
        myExtendedShape.getSpecialAttributes();
    }

    // ...
}
```

The issue here is that I cannot create a superclass for my extended shapes that would replace `<Undefined>` above. Specifically, if I create a superclass, I cannot extend the specific shapes that I want to extend in my subclasses due to a lack of multiple inheritance. If I replace `<Undefined>` with `Shape`, though, I then lose access to the methods in `SpecialInterface`.

I'm sure that this sort of multiple-inheritance problem has been solved before, but I cannot find the solution. I appreciate any and all suggestions on how to handle this situation.

Comment: I think you should be a bit more clear why the classes you mention don't work for <undefined>.  Why not make your own super type (MyShape) and use that, with all the methods you need defined?

Comment: @markspace Then how would you define `MyRectangle`? It would have to inherit from both `MyShape` and `Rectangle`, which is impossible.

Comment: Well there you go.  It's impossible.  I think this is an [XY problem:](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) you assume there must be a solution but there may be other approaches which are better. Define a MyCircleRectangle in terms of Shape and show us why that doesn't work.

Comment: @markspace is suggesting that you create an abstract superclass to represent your branch of the hierarchy. It is actually a good suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define `ManipulationService` like this:

```
class ManipulationService<T extends Shape & SpecialInterface> {
    public ManipulationService(T myExtendedShape) {
        // method from Shape
        myExtendedShape.onRotate(/* ... */);

        // method from SpecialInterface
        myExtendedShape.getSpecialAttributes();
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting -- I haven't seen the `&` character in a generic type like that. Would it still work even though `SpecialInterface` is an interface?

Comment: It will work exactly **because** it is an interface. Multiple inheritance is allowed, as long as you inherit no more than one class, and  you can inherit as many interfaces as you wish.

Comment: @nmagerko It works _only_ when `SpecialInterface` is an interface.